# Convert Excel order invoice to SQL INSERT Query

Tags: mysql, excel

Recently at the company where I work I've needed to import a bunch of orders from excel into our database so that they can be processed and shipped. Many of these excel documents have hundreds of columns. I'm looking for a clean way to convert multiple rows and columns containing order data into a dump of SQL queries.

[Here is what I'm working with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFlYP.png)

Each order is a single row identified by the `OrderID`, and the quantity of each product is defined in the cell which corresponds to the `ProductID`.

I'm using the following formula to convert each cell (if filled) into a value for an SQL query:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(ISBLANK(B3),"",("("&B3&", "&B$1&", "&$A3&"), ")))
```

The result for each filled cell is something like:

```
(1, 22, 1),
```

What I want to be able to do, is concatenate each cell (if filled) into one long string per order without having hundreds of columns filled with the same formula. Like this:

```
(5, 12, 23), (5, 13, 23), (100, 7, 23), (50, 1, 23), (100, 3, 23),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This -

VBA Code

```
Function InsStr(Product As Range, Order As String, Qty As Range)
Dim tmpString As String: tmpString = ""
Dim tmpCount As Integer: tmpCount = 1
    For Each cell In Qty
        If cell <> "" Then
        If tmpCount > 1 Then tmpString = tmpString & ","
        tmpString = tmpString & "(" & cell & "," & Product(tmpCount) & "," & Order & ")"
        End If
        tmpCount = tmpCount + 1
    Next cell
    InsStr = tmpString
End Function
```

and use Formula as `=InsStr(B1:X1,A3,B3:X3)`

Comment: Once I figured out how to insert the VBA it worked like magic. Since every SQL value must have a comma after it, I removed your `If tmpCount > 1 Then tmpString = tmpString & ","` line and changed `")"` to `"), "`. I used the formula as `=InsStr($B$1:$X$1,A3,B3:X3)`